# No name 'routes' in module 'app'pylint(no-name-in-module)

Tags: python, flask, import, python-import, importerror

I have a file "**init**.py" inside have this code

```
from flask import Flask 
app = Flask(__name__) 
from app import routes
```

And in a "routes.py" i have this code

```
from app import app
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    user = 'Cala'
return render_template('index.html', user=user)
```

In the first file in the 3 line say

> No name 'routes' in module 'app' pylint(no-name-in-module)

And in the second file in the firts line say

> Unable to import 'app' pylint(import-error)

Somebody know what is the problem?, is the fisrt time i do it this is probably is simple or all is wrong. Thanks

Comment: You can either rename a `route.py` file to `routes.py` or change `routes` to `route` when importing

Comment: Sorry the file is routes.py is a mistake in my question

Comment: Try changing `from app import routes` to `from api.routes import *`

Comment: `Unable to import 'api.routes`

Comment: Also, did you put both your files in app directory?

Comment: Yes is in the same directory, for the moment all files are in the same directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is that you didn't put both your files in `app` directory, since you are using `__init__.py` file. When doing `from app import app` it searches for an `app` directory or `app.py` file, if directory is not found. If directory is found, it searches for app variable inside `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Then what i have to do? Create a app directory and put the __init__.py file inside? I don't sure what i have to do. I'm a beginner in this.

Comment: You can do it in multiple ways, but i would recommend to create an `app` directory, put both files there, then create a `run.py` file outside this directory. In `run.py` you will have `from app import app` and `app.run()`. After that you should be able to run your application with `python run.py`

Comment: Now the routes.py don't show me error, the init file show me only if i run in terminal `No module named 'app'` and in the run.py show me `Unable to import 'app'`

Comment: You should have a project directory with `app` directory and `run.py` file inside it. In `app` directory you should have `__init__.py` file and `routes.py` file. You leave the code of `__init__.py` and `routes.py` files the same as in the question. I replicated those steps and everything works fine. Note: you should also import `render_template` function in `routes.py`

Comment: The routes file it is not finished but i run the run.py and execute to the routes file, is possible my problem is solved and i only have to finish the routes.py